# How to wake up threads from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, java-threads

I am trying to simulate elevator multithreading move.

On the first floor few passengers enter elevator and other passengers sleep(condition.await()). How to wake up/signal all other passengers threads on the second floor from Controller run() method(they are waiting because they didn't enter on the first floor)?

I have run() method for every passenger:

```
@Override
public void run () {
  lock.lock();
  try {
    while (!iCanEnter(passenger)) {  
      condition.await();
    }
    passenger.setState(TransportationState.IN_PROGRESS);
    leaveDispatchEnterElevator(passenger); 

    while (!iCanLeave(passenger)) {
        condition.await();
    }
    passenger.setState(TransportationState.COMPLETED);
    leaveElevatorEnterArrival(passenger);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Thread has been interrupted..." + e);
  } finally {
      lock.unlock();
  } 
}
```

And Controller run() method with elevator move:

```
@Override
public void run () {
  try {
    while (!isFinished()) {
      if(weCanMove()) {
        moveElevator();
      }
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Thread has been interrupted..." + e);
  }
}
```

Comment: IMHO you should try getting your feet wet with multithreading using a simpler scenario, and/or possibly finding a good tutorial. Here's a good one on BlockingQueue that may be useful to you in solving this problem: http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example